# Get log of Application Crash & ANR?

Tags: android, logging, crash, google-play

I found a section Crash & ANR in my Google play account

This list the crashes occurred but this is when user report the crash.

I have well managed application but some times it is being crashed as reported by one user.

What i want to get a log from device for the application crashes and save and send automatically.

[image]

### Is there any Process to get the details of all or Previous Crash from android systems on Next Application Start up?

Answer (score 0):

You can trap and log it manually, but this is usually solved by integrating crash handling and reporting services like [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/), [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/), and other similar services. There are some self-hosted, open source tools like [android-remote-stacktrace](https://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/) too.

The libraries are set to capture any unhandled exception your application, log the exception to a remote server so you can view it without requiring the user to send it to you manually, and will then allow the original exception to be rethrown as normal.

[Android Handling the Unexpected](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-handling-the-unexpected/) also covers the idea in detail with some sample code if you really want to do it yourself. That post also lists several more example external services.